# Como colocar uma linha vertical dentro da classe panel?

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3

Segue código:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title pull-left">
            Works fine for me!
        </div>
        <div class="panel-title pull-right">Text on the right</div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 pull-left">Coluna Esquerda</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">Coluna Direita</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quero colocar alguns formulários para direita e esquerda. Para isso preciso colocar um linha vertical no meio. Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar uma borda em algum dos blocos, apenas `left` ou `right`, dependendo do bloco que você escolher.

**Por exemplo:**

```
.pull-left{border-right:1px solid cor;}
```

Tem q lembrar q você colocou `col-md`, então quando chegar no maxwidth correspondente, precisa remover a borda para não ficar diferente os 2 blocos quando ficarem 100%.